# CAPTCHA при парсинге google

Tags: captcha, google-search, веб-скрейпинг

Пытаюсь парсить гугл, точнее с парсингом проблем нет, если бы не капча.
С капчей ситуация следующая:
Вместо выдачи перенаправляет на:
http://www.google.com/sorry/
беру оттуда id капчи и загружаю картинку от сюда:
[http://www.google.com/sorry/image?id={$id}&hl=en](http://www.google.com/sorry/image?id=%7B$id%7D&hl=en)
Картинка успешно распознается антигейтом и я получаю код.
А вот с этого момента начинаются проблемы - гугл принимать капчу упорно отказывается и после отправки ему капчи сим образом:
[http://www.google.com/sorry/Captcha?id={$id}&captcha={$captcha}&submit=Submit&continue=http://www.google.com/](http://www.google.com/sorry/Captcha?id=%7B$id%7D&captcha=%7B$captcha%7D&submit=Submit&continue=http://www.google.com/)
он снова выдает страницу ввода капчи.

Уже 20 раз перепроверил где какие куки в браузере берутся, как какая ссылка выглядит итп, но упорно не работает...
Подскажите пожалуйста в чем могут быть грабли, наверняка многие имели дело с парсингом гугла.
Заранее спасибо!

P.S. Код не прикладываю т.к. дело тут не в коде, а в том что мне нужно понять как гугл определяет что я пытаюсь его парсить.

Comment: а из чего парсите, Выж не из браузера это делаете)? Просто браузер идентифицирует себя при коннекте к серверу, может на этом и сыпется?
вообще по секрету скажу, проверки в гугле действительное есть, после одного скандала с маленькой компанией на букву М, которая в своем поисковике не добирая результатов, лезла в гугл)

Answer (score 3):

Вполне закономерное поведение Гугла. Зачем вашей программе притворяться браузером? Для этого есть **достаточно веская причина**?

Гугль не обязан любить ботов. А почему бы не поступить правильно и не воспользоваться специально созданным под примерно ваши задачи **поисковым API Google**?

https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

А определяет Вас Гугль, вполне возможно, по нагрузке, если число ваших запросов подозрительно велико для обычного пользователя. Попытайтесь, к примеру, "погуглить" вручную из под Tor, увидите то же самое.

Comment: Выдача API координально отличается от выдачи самого гугла.

Comment: логично. Потому что гугл затачивает вывод под конкретного пользователя. По запросу "делфи" кому то выведет о известной ide, кому то о [маслах](http://www.euroil.kg/), кому то древней [Греции и оракулах](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB), а кому и [фривольные картинки](http://ссылок.нет.и.не.будет).

Comment: Вы хотели сказать "кАрдинально"?

0. Акцентирую на не своей мысли еще раз: "Гугль затачивает ответ под конкретного пользователя". API - на сегодня объективнее. 

1. Во первых, он работает. Без заморочек с капчей. 

2. Во вторых, даже если Вам и удастся победить капчу, то Гугль не идиот и все равно не позволит с одного IP выполнять множество поисковых запросов. Это знают, например, пользователи Tor, так как там множество пользователей маскируются за небольшим числом IP-адресов, то пользоваться Гуглем из под Tor практически невозможно.

Comment: жаль Владимир Иванович Даль давно умер. А то еще одно слово мог бы вписать в свой словарь - **координально**

Answer (score 1):

Все дело в том, что при загрузке картинки капчи - google передает кукисы, без которых у вас ничего не выйдет, если картинку загрузить curl -ом и **пересохранить** куки то все работает на ура

Answer (score 0):

делай паузы. у Яндекса - 3-4 секунды между запросами, у Гугла 2-3 секунды. и они даже капчу не запрашивают

Answer (score 0):

Все дело в том что гугл с капчей (с рисунком, а не страницей) шлет отдельную куку, и именно эту куку надо отсылать обратно с кодом.

Answer (score 0):

Помимо решения капчи можно повторять неудачный запрос через другую прокси. По нашему опыту это работает быстрее и надежнее, чем решать капчу.

Или как [уже говорил(а)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/254262/446754) Softa, ты можешь использовать API от Google, но его выдача действительно отличается, от того что видят пользователи.

В качестве альтернативы ты можешь использовать [Google Search API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) от SerpApi. Он решает капчи, меняет прокси, полностью имитируя действия человека. Это гарантирует, что ты получишь то, что действительно видят пользователи. Попробуй [Playground](https://serpapi.com/playground), чтобы проверить различные варианты настроек.

Пример использования:

```js
const SerpApi = require('google-search-results-nodejs');
const search = new SerpApi.GoogleSearch("secret_api_key");

const params = {
  engine: "google",
  q: "Coffee",
  location: "Austin, Texas, United States",
  google_domain: "google.com",
  gl: "us",
  hl: "en"
};

const callback = function(data) {
  console.log(data);
};

// Show result as JSON
search.json(params, callback);
```

Результат:

```
{
  "search_metadata": {
    "id": "5ca75b3ade98341bb4fb69b3",
    "status": "Success",
    "created_at": "2019-04-05 13:42:18 UTC",
    "processed_at": "2019-04-05 13:42:18 UTC",
    "google_url": "https://www.google.com/search?q=Coffee&oq=Coffee&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8",
    "total_time_taken": 5.47
  },
  "search_parameters": {
    "q": "Coffee",
    "google_domain": "google.com",
    "device": "desktop"
  },
  "search_information": {
    "total_results": 3460000000,
    "time_taken_displayed": 0.6,
    "query_displayed": "Coffee"
  },

[...]

}
```

> Я работаю на SerpApi